# nodeSelect / Affinity in innodb cluster under kubernetes

Tags: mysql-innodb-cluster, nodeselector

Is it possible to choose/schedule special worker nodes in a kubernetes innodb cluster to avoid using master or longhorn nodes?

The mysql template is:

```
apiVersion: mysql.oracle.com/v2
kind: InnoDBCluster
metadata:
  name: mycluster
spec:
  secretName: mypwds
  tlsUseSelfSigned: true
  instances: 3
  version: 8.3.0
  router:
    instances: 1
    version: 8.3.0
  datadirVolumeClaimTemplate:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 4Gi
  mycnf: |
    [mysqld]
    max_connections=150
```

nodeSelect or affinity orders seemed not to be part of the innodbcluster object.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for all guys with the same question... ;-)

This can be done by adding some more lines to the yaml file in a seperate section:

```
  podSpec:
    nodeSelector:
      noderole: worker
```

There has to be a "noderole=worker" label at the node.